# Can I set httpSession using js file which is included in my jsp?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc. i want to set attributes to my httpSession. I want to do something like

```
 // this is inluded in my js file
function setName(name){
   <%session.setAttribute("name", name)%>
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your problem.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/341573/JavaScript-How-to-Set-values-to-Session-in-Javascr

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it will work.You should try to know the Principle of the jsp:

1.the `<%session.setAttribute("name", name)%>` is java code,it will excute in the server before the jsp is return to the browser.
2.the function `setname()` is js code, it will only work in browser.
3.you can see response in browser finally like that:

```
// this is inluded in my js file
function setName(name){

}
```

yeah,there will be nothing in setname;

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly what you want. You can't set attribute in your httpSession with javascript cause it's client side. If you want to set attributes in your httpSession, you have to get the name server-side (with a get or a post) and change your httpSession in your java.

If you want to change it dynamically, you have to use Ajax to do your request.